# How to get resources used for FINISHED hadoop jobs from YARN logs using job names?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a unix shell script which runs multiple hive scripts. I have given Job names for every hive queries inside the hive scripts.

What I need is that at the end of the shell script, I want to retrieve the resources (in terms of memory used,containers) used for the hive queries based on the job names from the YARN logs/application having appstatus as 'FINISHED'

How do I do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull this information from the Yarn History server via rest apis.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html

Scroll through this documentation and you will see examples of how to get cluster level information on jobs executed and then how to get information on individual jobs.